Issue with WKWebView not Automatically Scrolling Above the Keyboard in iOS 17
I'm currently working on an iOS application that utilizes a WKWebView to display web content with interactive forms. When the user focuses on an HTML input element, the keyboard appears, but I've encountered a problem where the view does not automatically scroll to bring the input field into view.
Environment:
iOS 17
Xcode [15.3]
Problem:
The WKWebView content does not automatically scroll to reveal the input field when the keyboard is presented. This is causing a poor user experience as the user cannot see what they are typing.
Do nothing, just 8  <\input> .
